# use batch file to download a file from a website then ask user input y or n to run downloaded file?

Tags: file, batch-file, download

not sure if this is the most effective method to download the file and then was wondering how to start the file as admin if the user says yes to start the file the code I have downloads the file but it displays a big downloading box while doing so any other way to do this thanks for the help in advance the code I have tried is below

```
 powershell -Command "Invoke-WebRequest https://www.website.com/download/file.exe -Outfile C:\download\file.exe"
```

pause

Comment: If you're using Windows 10, or higher, you could always try downloading with cURL. You probably don't need a Y|N prompt, because Windows willI likely warn the end user, when they try to run the downloaded file anyhow.

Comment: As Compo mentioned, you could do this with cURL like the following: `if not exist "C:\download\file.exe" %__APPDIR__%curl.exe -s -o "C:\download\file.exe" https://www.website.com/download/file.exe` [cURL](https://ss64.com/nt/curl.html)

Comment: what would be the best way if I wasn't sure if the client was using any certain OS ?

Comment: Not to rely on PowerShell! either! Any batch file intended to be able to function on multiple older versions of Windows should be coded accordingly. So you would select the methodology within the script, depending upon the OS version and/or the utilities available to it. And please do not forget what I said previously. On modern versions of Windows, at least, it is common that the system will display a security dialog box to the end user, if they try to invoke a file which has just been downloaded.

Comment: I just want to download the file after the user makes a selection in the menu to do so... but the powershell version seems like a lot harder way of doing what I am trying to do ... download a file then run it after download is complete